# How to list customer's payment methods?

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to list the user's payment methods in their settings in case they want to edit or delete them. Mainly, I would like to get the brand, last 4 digits and the expiration date.

Here is the function in my backend:

```
exports.listPaymentMethods = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const customerId = data.customer_id;
  const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer: customerId,
    type: "card",
  });
});
```

I call this function on the client using the following:

```
func listPaymentMethods(customerID: String) {
FirebaseReferenceManager.functions.httpsCallable("listPaymentMethods").call(["customer_id": customerID]) { (response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("failed to list customer's payment methods: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    if let response = (response?.data as? [String: Any]) {
        print(response)
    }
}
```

}

However, I am getting the error "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format"

Any help would be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: I could be missing something but your backend doesn't seem to return anything? You likely have to do something with `paymentMethods` , maybe `return paymentMethods;`? But more likely you need to do a bit more in terms of forming a JSON response, like run some code to map over `paymentMethods.data` and create an array with the specific information your app needs, rather than the raw stripe-node response object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to return paymentMethods.data from my server to the client using:

```
exports.listPaymentMethods = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const customerId = data.customer_id;
  const paymentMethods = await stripe.paymentMethods.list({
    customer: customerId,
    type: "card",
  });
  const paymentMethodsData = paymentMethods.data;
  return {
    paymentMethodsData: paymentMethodsData,
  };
});
```

And on my client, I had to call the function like this:

```
func listPaymentMethods(customerID: String) {
FirebaseReferenceManager.functions.httpsCallable("listPaymentMethods").call(["customer_id": customerID]) { (response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("failed to list customer's payment methods: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    if let response = (response?.data as? [String: Any]) {
        let data = (response["paymentMethodsData"] as! Array<Any>?)
        print(data!)
    }
}
```

}